# php, .htaccess - redirect non extension to index + redirect usernames to user page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched a lot in google and stackoverflow but didn't find the complete answer...

What im trying to do is:

1) Redirect all non-extension addresses to their pages. For example: home -> home.php

2) Redirect usernames to a page that searches the username and if exists, then load another page. For example: www.example.com/michael will redirect to go.php and gets "michael" and if user exsists; goes to user.php?id=michael

Its totally like facebook and twitter! Where as if you type "home" it goes to homepage and if you type your username, it goes to your profile!

How can I do such a thing?

---

**EDIT**: or maybe a .htaccess that sends anything after the first slash to a page. For example:

```
www.example.com/this/is/test
```

will be:

```
www.example.com/index.php?var1=this&var2=is&var3=test
```

and then the index.php page will decide to do what...

Comment: Then `/home` is a fixed string. Right? If not, what's the difference between `www.example.com/michael` and `www.example.com/home`? Both have the same structure and both hold a variable.

Comment: home is actually a page called home.php, also pages like profile -> profile.php etc. But /michael and anything that is not a page will go to a page like user.php?id=michael and assume them as a username

Comment: Okay. But I guess you want `profile` to be redirected too, for example, and unless you are willing to have one rule for each name, it would be better to have a pattern to make a single rule for all of them, if possible. That's regarding number 1 only. Number 2 is clear.

Comment: I've just edited my post...Look at it...Maybe this is a better way...

Comment: I saw it. That's much better and versatile.

Comment: So any clue for writing such a RewriteRule?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*     index.php?var1=%1&var2=%2&var3=%3   [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://www.example.com/this/is/test`

To

`http://www.example.com/index.php?var1=this&var2=is&var3=test`

**All parameters are optional with a maximum of 3.**

If more are needed, add `([^/]+)?/?` for each one at the right end of

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`

line and add keys (`varN`) accordingly to index.php query in the RewriteRule, using `%N` to back reference them.

Comment: Well its says Page Not Found! :(

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the complete entered URL into a comment.

Comment: Please try with [R] instead of [L] so you can see the redirected URL. That's a temporary modification to find out if it is redirecting properly.

Comment: Done. Result is same as before!

Comment: Please try again, I modified my answer.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I did test and worked fine. I modified the answer again, please give it another try.

Comment: Sorry I got to go...Will test it later...BTW thanks a LOT for helping!

Comment: Oh Thanks Man!! Yeah that was the problem!! It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please remove my site name from your comment above? Really appreciate that...

Comment: @Michael I wasn't around and just saw your request. Sure. I deleted the comment. Glad I could help with the answer.